# Unable to get json parsing for specific field name

Tags: java, android, json

I am working on Yahoo Finance. Trying to parse json data from a url, such as [Google finance data](http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/GOOGL/quote?format=json).

I am fetching data into a string "str" and then parsing the json data to reach the name field inside resources.

the json data is :

```
{
    "list":{
        "meta":{
            "type":"resource-list",
            "start":0,
            "count":1
        },
        "resources":[
            {
                "resource":{
                    "classname":"Quote",
                    "fields":{
                        "name":"Alphabet Inc.",
                        "price":"710.489990",
                        "symbol":"GOOGL",
                        "ts":"1452891600",
                        "type":"equity",
                        "utctime":"2016-01-15T21:00:00+0000",
                        "volume":"3833751"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to use this code, but it is not working - need to reach the "name" field:

```
str4 = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);  
//str holds the json data given above- checked.
JSONObject str1 = new JSONObject(str4);
JSONObject list = str1.getJSONObject("list");
JSONArray resources = list.getJSONArray("resorces");
JSONObject fields = resources.getJSONObject(1);
str2 = fields.getString("name");
```

Comment: what problem are u getting... elaborate with exception stack trace if any

Comment: If you only have one item in the array, then you should call `resources.getJSONObject(0);`

Comment: Also, you misspelled the word `resources`.

Comment: @iturki
I cleared the errors you mention both are cleared ....
`JSONArray resources = list.getJSONArray("resources");
             JSONObject resource = resources.getJSONObject(0);
             JSONObject fields = resource.getJSONObject("fields");`

still it is not getting the data

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial <-- You should try this link for learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notices three issues with your code:

- you have one item in your JSONArray, so you should retrieve item 0, not item 1.
- you misspelled the word `resources` in your code.

Also, I think you didn't retrieve the fields correctly. This should do it:

```
JSONObject str1 = new JSONObject(str4);
JSONObject list = str1.getJSONObject("list");
JSONArray resources = list.getJSONArray("resources");
JSONObject fields = resources.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("resource").getJSONObject("fields");
str2 = fields.getString("name");
```

Comment: You are awesome Man ... this helped

Comment: @ArunYadav Glad I can help.

Comment: I guess you misspelled "misspeeled" deliberately... `:-)`

Comment: @halfer looool sure I did ;)